# When Cauchy Schwarz is equality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1 = x_1 + iy_1$ and $z_2 = x_2 + iy_2$.  Show that $|x_1x_2 + y_1y_2|=|z_1||z_2|$ if and only if $z_1z_2 = 0$ or $z_2 = \alpha z_1$, $\alpha$ real.

The "if" part is relatively simple but I'm having trouble showing "only if".  Here's what I've got:

Assume $|x_1x_2 + y_1y_2| = |z_1||z_2|$.  Then $$(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)^2 = (x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2) \\ x_1^2x_2^2+2x_1x_2y_1y_2 + y_1^2y_2^2 = x_1^2x_2^2 + x_1^2y_2^2 + y_1^2x_2^2 + y_1^2y_2^2 \\ 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 = x_1^2y_2^2+y_1^2x_2^2 \\ x_1^2y_2^2 - 2x_1y_2y_1x_2 + y_1^2x_2^2 = 0 \\ (x_1y_2-y_1x_2)^2 = 0 \\ x_1y_2=y_1x_2$$

But then I get stuck.  I can see that $z_2=0$, $z_1=0$, and $z_2=\alpha z_1$ each satisfy that last condition.  But I don't see how to show that those are the only solutions.

Assuming I'm heading in the right direction, how can I continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you appear to be proceeding in nearly the right direction.

To give you a hint, if any $x_{i}$ or $y_{i}$ is $0$, then $z_2 \times z_1=0$

If you assume that none of them are $0$, note that your last equation can be divided by $x_1y_1$.